# Analysing an integral with its inverse integral [Image, and good explanation inside]

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

- I have a function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$
- This means $f^{-1}(x) = (\pm)\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$, where the negative solution is ignored for this problem.

If I want to find a relation between the $\color{green}{\text{green-ish area}}$ and the $\color{red}{\text{red-ish area}}$ with the help of integrals, I would find the integral for $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$.

- $\int \color{red}{f(x)}\,dx = \sqrt{1+x^2}$
- $\int \color{green}{f^{-1}(x)}\,dx = (\pm)\sqrt{1-x^2}$

For this we would only need to study the positive area, and as such the negative solution is ignored, as previously mentioned.

Now say we would want to find where $\int_0^a f(x)\,dx = \color{blue}{2}\cdot\int^{b}_0f^{-1}(x)\,dx$, we could make the statement that $\color{orange}{b = f(a)} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$.

As such we have the comparison,
$$\left[\sqrt{1+x^2}\right]^a_0 = \color{blue}{2}\cdot\left[\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]^{\color{orange}{f(a)}}_0 \iff \sqrt{1+a^2} = 2\cdot\sqrt{1-(f(a))^2} \qquad(1)$$

Using Wolfram I get the following solutions for $a$

> Solve[Sqrt[1 + a^2] == 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2/(1 + a^2)], {a}]
>
> $\{\{a \rightarrow -1\}, \{a \rightarrow 1\}, \{a \rightarrow -i\cdot \sqrt 3\}, \{a \rightarrow i\cdot \sqrt 3\}\}$

---

In the image I've portrayed the situation when $a = 1 \implies b = f(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.7$

[image: Figure 1]

And **HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK**.

$$\int^1_0 f(x) = \sqrt{2} - 1 \not= 2\cdot \int^{1/\sqrt{2}}_0 f^{-1}(x) = 2\cdot\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}} - 1\right) \approx -0.59$$

I've done something wrong, and I'm not sure what. I'm sorry for the long text, but I don't want people to think I haven't tried my best.

Edit: Noticed my equation (1) was wrong, I haven't changed it, but the outcome was $a \rightarrow 0$, which obviously doesn't yield a correct answer either.

Comment: The method you use is overly complicated, so I am not surprised something goes wrong. I suggest you use instead the simple relationship that RED AREA + GREEN AREA = RECTANGLE (with area ab). Use this to see if there is 1 : 2 ratio possible.

Comment: @M.Wind If I understood you correctly, I should set $\int^a_0f(x) = \frac{ab}{2} = \frac{a\cdot f(a)}{2}$. Wolfram gives me $a = 0$ here though. I know I'm over-complicating stuff, but I'm so stuck in my own thinking box atm. I'll try get some sleep and see if I come up with something tomorrow.

Comment: You said that the Red Area should be twice the Green Area. That means Red Area = 2/3 of the Rectangle. This leads to the equation $sqr(1 + a^2) - 1 = 2/3 * a^2/sqr(1 + a^2)$. It has a trivial solution $a = 0$, but also a good one: $a = sqr(3)$. Check it out!